# curl_init not working. how to use CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION properly?

Tags: php, curl

this code was working for a period of time pretty good:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init("***");
$fp = fopen("example_homepage.html", "w");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

but now it's giving me page with :" Object Moved This document may be found here"
i tried to solve it with "curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);" :

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init("***");
$fp = fopen("example_homepage.html", "w");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

but now it's giving me blank page, I'm doing something wrong? I tried some other things but it was always giving me blank one. I don't know much about programming, hope that you guys can help me

Comment: What does curl_error($ch) return?

Comment: with echo curl_error($ch); it gives "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"

Answer (score 1):

If you are not going to send any sensitive data, a quick fix would be to turn off the SSL verification,

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```